# vb.net TWAIN project needs to fill picturebox

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.0, twain

[TWAIN vb.net Project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1RJps_0bdhsRWlaV0FTR1NrdkU)

Can anyone help me.
I converted a **C#** application to **vb.net 2012** and got it working.
I am hoping to be able to do a single scan of a receipt and save it to a **PictureBox** instead of needing to save it to file.
I spent days playing with it and could not get it to fill a picture box.
Ideally it would be perfectly zoomed to the picture box.
I don't need multiple pages like this app can do.
It will always be a single receipt being scanned.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this is what you are looking for](https://bytescout.com/products/developer/scansdk/bytescoutscansdk_first_step_with_visual_basic_net.html) ;)

And then configure the picturebox like

```
picturebox.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
```